# Given a column of int64, make a REST call for each value, return results to a single table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to roll my own CMDB report. Given a list of asset IDs, I can pull network information for them singly, or ensemble. I would like to use Excel and Power Query to do the hard work.

The IDs are entered manually

Thus, for a list like this

| ID |
| --- |
| 1001 |
| 1002 |
| 1003 |

I can make a single call like this

```
https://my.cmdb.server/RESTService.pl?method=lst_asset:arg01=1001;arg02=1002;arg03=1003;
```

Or I can make several calls like this

```
https://my.cmdb.server/RESTService.pl?method=lst_asset:arg01=1003
https://my.cmdb.server/RESTService.pl?method=lst_asset:arg01=1002
https://my.cmdb.server/RESTService.pl?method=lst_asset:arg01=1001
```

How can I use the input table to generate one or the other URIs and make the call/ s?

Answer (score 2):

You'd be best off reading https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/  but in general, in powerquey, set up a query similar to this, and name the query **call**. It becomes a function. Change the code to do what you need to do with the contents that get returned. Here I assume I return a table

```
(item) as table => 
let Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://my.cmdb.server/RESTService.pl?method=lst_asset:arg01="&Text.From(item))),
Data = Source{0}[Data]
in Data
```

add column, custom column, with

```
  =call([ID])
```

in the other table